# How to remove the error : expected unqualified -id at end of input

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Dist
{
    int feet;
    float inches;
public:
    enter()
    {
        cout<<"\nenter feet ";
        cin>>feet;
        cout<<"\nenter inches";
        cin>>inches;
    }
    display()
    {
        cout<<feet<<"'-"<<inches;
    }
    scale(Dist d1, float scalefactor)
    {
        d1.feet= d1.feet*scalefactor;
        d1.inches=d1.inches*scalefactor;
        while(d1.inches>=12)
            {
                d1.inches=12-d1.inches;
                d1.feet++;
            }

};
main()
{
    Dist d1,d2;
    d1.enter();
    d1.scale(d1,0.5);
    d1.display();

}   //error is in this line
```

error is in the last line. This code is the solution for the question

> Define a class Dist with int feet and float inches. Define member function that displays distance in 1’-2.5” format. Also define member function scale ( ) function that takes object by reference and scale factor in float as an input argument. The function will scale the distance accordingly.
>   For example, 20’-5.5” and Scale Factor is 0.5 then answer is 10’-2.75”

Comment: If the tutorial/course you take does not teach you how to properly define a function (that includes a return type), then you should probably think about using some good c++ books instead: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242)

Comment: Your scale method is missing a closing brace

Answer (score 1):

There no one method return type in your methods. You have to mention method return in declaration.

```
Like
    void enter()
    void display()
    void scale()

Also for main method
    void main()
Return int value for nain is good
practice.
int main(){ 
    //your code here
    return 0;
}
```